# JS Многомерный массив, как подсчитать вложенность

Tags: javascript, массивы, рекурсия

Нужно написать универсальную функцию для подсчёта вложенности многомерного массива. Консоль возвращает ошибку "Uncaught TypeError: ar_elem.forEach is not a function". Помогите домучить)

```
    var People = [
        [1, [ 2, [ 3 ] ]],
        ["Rustam", 25, 3, 4],
        ["Ruslan", 35],
        ["Aleksey", 29],
        ["Vovan", 23]
    ];
    var length=0;
    function f1(ar_elem) {
        ar_elem.forEach(function(item, i, arr) {
            console.log(item.length);
            if (item.length !== 0) {
                length++;
                f1(item);
            };
        });
    };
    f1(People);
```

Comment: а какой ответ ожидается для данного примера?

Comment: Нужна максимальная вложенность(глубина) массива

Answer (score 2):

У вас нет проверки является ли элемент массивом - и на максимальном уровне рекурсии встретится немассив, для него нет `forEach`

Не сосвсем понятно вам надо посчитать **общее количество** вложенных массивов, или **максимальную вложенность**? (по вашему коду - первое, но по тексту вопроса - второе)

Если **общее количество** вложенных массивов:

```js
var People = [
    [1, [ 2, [ 3 ] ]],
    ["Rustam", 25, 3, 4],
    ["Ruslan", 35],
    ["Aleksey", 29],
    ["Vovan", 23]
];

function f1(item, level = 0){ 
    if (item instanceof Array){
        return (level > 0 ? 1 : 0) + item.map(function(value, index){
            return f1(value, level + 1)
        }).reduce((a, b) => a + b , 0)
    }
    return 0;
}

console.log(f1(People))
```

Если **максимальную вложенность**:

```js
var People = [
    [1, [ 2, [ 3 ] ]],
    ["Rustam", 25, 3, 4],
    ["Ruslan", 35],
    ["Aleksey", 29],
    ["Vovan", 23]
];

Array.prototype.max = function() {
    return Math.max.apply(null, this);
  };

function f1(item, level = 0){ 
    if (item instanceof Array){
        return item.map(function(value, index){
            return f1(value, level + 1)
        }).max() - (level > 0 ? 0 : 1) // Если главный массив не считаем
    }
    return level;
}

console.log(f1(People))
```

Comment: 7 почему-то пишет. А уровень вложенности 4... или 3, смотря как считать

Comment: А - я не понял задачу из вашего кода. Оно считает все количество вложенных массивов, а вам надо максимальное. Тогда еще проще.

Comment: Вот - ваше решение. Максимальный уровень вложенности выводит.

Comment: Сделал ответы для обоих вариантов.

Comment: Спасибо всем! 
Нужна была максимальная вложенность. Вроде корректно показывает

Answer (score 1):

```js
const getDepth = array => {
    let i = 0;
    while(array.length){
         i++;
         array = array.reduce( (level, el) => {
              if(Array.isArray(el)) level.push(...el);
              return level;
         }, []);
    }
    return i;
}

var People = [
    [2, [ 3, [ 4 ] ]],
    ["Rustam", 25, 3, 4],
    1,
    [2, [ 3, [ 4 , [5], 4, [5, 5, [6], 5], 4 ], 3], 2],1
    ["Ruslan", 35],
    ["Aleksey", 29],
    ["Vovan", 23]
];

console.log(getDepth([1]));
console.log(getDepth([1, [2]]));
console.log(getDepth([1, [2, 2], [2, [3, 3], 2]]));

console.log(getDepth(People));
```

Comment: Работает, но в последнем массиве (People) разве не 5 максимальная вложенность ?

Comment: @allweek цифра 6 в самой длинной строке на 6ом уровне - 
`1,[2, [ 3, [ 4 , [5], 4, [5, 5, [6], 5], 4 ], 3], 2]`

Comment: 1,
    [2, [ 3, [ 4 , [5], 4, [5, 5, [6], 5], 4 ], 3], 2],1
Вот эта единичка перед скобкой смущает меня. Я думал это самостоятельный элемент массива, не входящий ни в одну другую группу

Comment: @allweek ну да, но он на 1ом уровне вложенности) 2 - на втором, 3 - на третьем, итд до 6ого